# I am asking for the user to input a title, but I want to compare the "input" with my text file

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

library=mylibrary

tmp=mylibrary.tmp

function add_book {

echo Please enter the book title:

read title

existed=`awk -F '$1 == $title' $library | wc -l`

  echo $existed

  if (( $existed == 0 ))

  then 

    echo Please enter the author:

    read author

    location=library

    updated=$title,$author,$location,`date +%F`

    echo $updated >> $library

    echo $updated return successfully!

  else

    echo "Book Exist!"

  fi
```

((WHAT I WANT TO DO IS COMPARE THE TITLES AND IF THE TITLE EXIST THEN ECHO "BOOK EXIST"

I WANT IT TO COMPARE THE INPUT WITH THE TEXT FILE))

HERE IS A SAMPLE TEXT FILE:

```
Title,Author,Location,Date Added

jj,jj,library,2013-11-14

hjj,hj,library,2013-11-14

jhj,hjh,library,2013-11-14
```

Comment: and what is the trouble ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has quite a few issues but this seems to be a blocker issue:

```
existed=`awk -F '$1 == $title' $library | wc -l`
```

Change that to:

```
existed=$(awk -v title="$title" -F '$1 == title{i++} End{print i}' "$library")
```

1. SHELL doesn't expand varialle inside single quotes
2. To pass a shell variable to awk use `-v name="$value"` syntax